# What does Benjamin Graham mean by debt? (Intelligent Investor Enterprising Investor Criteria 1B)

Tags: stocks

From Chapter 15. Stock Selection for the Enterprising Investor:

"1. Financial condition: (a) Current assets at least 1 1⁄2 times current
liabilities, and (b) debt not more than 110% of net current assets
(for industrial companies)"

What is debt in this context?  Does the author talk about Total Debt (Long-Term debt + Short Term debt usually available in the Balance Sheet)?

Comment: I guess it's Borrowing only. Still expecting others to answer.